# MongoDB: Merge of two update requests possible?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Do I have to do two updates, if I want to unset one value and set another value? Or is it possible to merge both together?

```
Collection.update(
    { _id: id },
    { $unset: { 'status.editing': '' } }
);

Collection.update(
    { _id: id },
    { $set: { 'status.version': timestamp } }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
Collection.update(
    { _id: id },
    { 
        $unset: { 'status.editing': '' },
        $set: { 'status.version': timestamp }
    }
);
```

See [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) and [$set](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

It is also possible to set or unset multiple fields at the time with

```
{ $unset: { quantity: "", instock: "" } }
```

or

```
{ $set:
   {
     quantity: 500,
     details: { model: "14Q3", make: "xyz" },
     tags: [ "coats", "outerwear", "clothing" ]
   }
}
```